# Create a responsive HTML table so that the right cell can move to the bottom

Tags: html, css, iphone

I have a one row, two cell table. Simple. (Scroll down just a bit here http://staging.mragg.com/) Right now the right cell gets cut off on the iPhone as it is too wide. Is there a way to get the right cell to drop down and just be beneath the left cell on the iPhone screen?

(I know how to target the iPhone already... I just need the CSS code that would, I guess, break up the table in the right way for the smaller screens...)

Current table code:

```
.bottom-table  {
background: #323232;
color: #FFFFFF;
border: none;
border-radius: 10px;
width: 80%;
text-align: center;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}

#bottomTable{
margin-top: -30px !important;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.bottom-table td {
border: 0px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-top: 20px;
padding-bottom: 40px;
vertical-align: top;
}

.bottom-table td:first-child {
border-right: 1px solid;
border-right-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Better solution: wrap the table in `<div style="overflow:auto;">...</div>` so users can scroll it horizontally without scrolling the entire page.

Comment: Please add your code to the question in stead of just linking to your site. This way the question remains relevant to others after you fixed the problem.

Comment: @Blazemonger That's a band-aid, not a real fix... I'm doing this for aesthetic reasons, not purely functionality.

Comment: If you're displaying tabular data, it should remain in rows and columns. If you're not, you probably shouldn't be using a table in the first place -- consider replacing it with an orderered list or definition list.

Comment: @Blazemonger I do not think I could get the same design effects with a list... Take a look at the page to see what I mean. And do please correct me if I am mistaken...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're displaying tabular data, it should remain in rows and columns. If you're not, you probably shouldn't be using a table in the first place -- consider replacing it with an ordered list or definition list, or just a couple of `<div>`s, and styling that to suit your needs. CSS is sufficiently powerful nowadays that HTML can be made to look any way you like, so [semantic](http://diveintohtml5.info/semantics.html) [HTML markup](http://html5doctor.com/lets-talk-about-semantics/) is the preferred way to build.

That said, the easiest way to do what you want is:

```
.bottom-table td {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this CSS code:

```
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 480px) {
    .bottom-table td {
         display: inline-block;
         min-width: 200px;
    }
    .bottom-table td:first-child {
        border: none;
    }
}
```

Add this CSS code under your current CSS and resize the window under 480px to see the result ;-)

Comment: If youre going for media queries in ie9 you also have to disable Compatibilty mode in the top of your head (before all other meta tags).
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">